# netlogo: comparing variable of two different turtle

Tags: variables, compare, netlogo

I am trying to compare variable of "capabilities" and "prevalues" on the same patch. If number on value = one of number on resource list, then do something. 
This is what I have:

```
capabilities-own [ resource ]
prevalues-own [ value ] 

to setup
  clear-all
  ......
  ask capabilities 
   [ set resource (list 1 2)]
  ask prevalues 
   [set value ((random 4) + 1)]
  ....
  reset-ticks
end

to compare
 ask capabilities-here
    [if any? prevalues-here 
     [ ask one-of prevalues-here   
        [ ifelse ( value = one-of resource)
            [ move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = red] ]
            [die]
]]]
```

But I got 
 RUNTIME ERROR: PREVALUES breed does not own variable RESOURCE

I also try to use other code, like this :

```
to compare
  ask capabilities-here
    [ ifelse prevalues-here with [value] = one-of [resource] of myself  
        [ move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = red] ]
        [die]]
end
```

It results RUNTIME ERROR : WITH expected true/false....

Appreciates your kindly help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `ifelse (value = one-of resource)` is causing the first problem. resource is an agent variable for capabilities, but you haven't told NetLogo which capability's resource to compare the prevalue's value to. A turtle is aware of its own agent variables and the patch variables for the patch it is on, but if you want to get something from another turtle, you have to explicitly say so.

Also, do you want it to randomly select one value from the list of resources, or do you just want to check the value appears somewhere in the list?

I think you want something like this (not tested):

```
to compare
 ask capabilities-here
   [ if any? prevalues-here 
     [ ask one-of prevalues-here   
       [ ifelse member? value ([resource] of myself)
         [ move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = red] ]
         [ die ]
]]]
```

This assumes you want to check if it's in the list at all, which is what I think you mean from your first paragraph. If you want to randomly select an item from the list and check if it matches that, you will need something more like:

```
 [ let this-resource one-of [resource] of myself
 ask one-of prevalues-here   
   [ ifelse value = this-resource
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jen. You're such a big help to me. I use your second code for my purpose. I still got runtime error : PREVALUES breed does not own variable RESOURCE. So I did a little modification to yours. And it works well. : '[ let this-resource item (random length resource) resource'

Comment: `item (random length resource) resource` can be shortened to simply `one-of resource`

Comment: Thanks @SethTisue. I've tried your suggestion. It produces runtime error. Maybe because the list length is different between variables.

Comment: @Seth - DUH! Feel free to always fix my code directly

Comment: @dya I promise you that `item (random length resource) resource` and `one-of resource` are 100% equivalent.

Comment: I use Jen's with the modification , and it produces runtime error : Can't find element ... of the list [ .. .. ], which is only length of 2.

Comment: @SethTisue Sorry, I missed interpreting your code. Your code works well too~